# PHP associative array get values in an array

Tags: php, arrays, object, key

i fetch the user's group in facebook using graph api...
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=100000004811603%2Fgroups / with `user_groups` permission and a valid `access_token`

i turned it into array using this function i found in google:

```
 function objectToArray($d) {
        if (is_object($d)) {
        // Gets the properties of the given object
        // with get_object_vars function
        $d = get_object_vars($d);
    }

    if (is_array($d)) {
        /*
        * Return array converted to object
        * Using __FUNCTION__ (Magic constant)
        * for recursive call
        */
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $d);
    }
    else {
        // Return array
        return $d;
    }
}
```

now i have the the results in this variable

```
$groups = objectToArray($obj);
```

and now what i want to do is to extract the values of `id` keys and put it in an array that will looks like this:

```
$new = array("group id 1","group id 2","group id 3","group id 4"); // and so on....
```

can someone help me plsss

Comment: Why are you converting from an object to an array? What does the object look like? Can you run `var_dump($obj);`?

Comment: i think you may use json while using facebook graph, Please share what you exactly want to do?

Comment: @jonathan i've edited my post sir... there is a link below..

Comment: @rohit i want to gather the group ids so that i can use them to post in each group...

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary the `$obj` is the variable with the `json_decode()` of the results of the graph api

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag , you should use json_decode where you are getting result from facebook graph. Then by accessing their property you can get group id.

Comment: yes sir... but i dont know how to extract the `id` values from the results and put it in a new array....coz i only nid the `id`s

Comment: ok.use print_r($obj) and see the result. If result is comig correctly then store $obj->facebook returned group id variable in json response and store it into an array

Comment: how sir??? is it okay if you can provide and example???

Comment: $obj=json_decode(response variable you get from facebook graph);
$id=$obj->group id response identifier in graph result;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ids=array();
foreach ($obj->data as $group){
$ids[]=$group->id;
}
```

as you can see we're taking the `json_decode()` result and iterating over all the elements (groups) and storing only the id into the array `$ids`

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /home/alylores/public_html/gd/clean2/tryinter.php on line 35

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to convert complete `$obj` to an array. You can access its members with `->` operator. So to collect all the `id` member of `data` member of `$obj`, you have to do something like:

```
$group_ids = array();
foreach ($obj->data as $group_data) {
  $group_ids[] = $group_data->id;
}
```

Comment: i got it already sir...

$ids = array();
    foreach ($obj->data as $group){
    $ids[]= $group->id;
    }

Comment: @JulianPaoloDayag, you have to thank this guy too.. he helped me to correct the $obj->data

Comment: yeah sir... but i can only have a answer